# iOS7 uitablecell white background

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios7

This happened with me after installing iOS7

The UITableController has clear background color and I use image as cell background and this image has transparent color

So, it suppose to have the color of the view but what happened that it has the white color

it works on iOS6 and iOS5 perfectly, but on iOS7 it shows white color on the cell

Comment: You should really go ask this on the Apple Developer Forums. You shouldn't be discussing any iOS 7 beta stuff outside of that forum. Plus, everyone else is ere and you will probably find better help anyway.

Comment: i'm mentioning the problem and how to solve it. because so many app has UI issue after i installed ios7. also i mentioned this in apple forum.

Answer (score 8):

The solution was simple, just set the cell with transperant color too.

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

and it works fine now

Comment: You still might mention this on Radar; if the behavior changed between iOS 6 and iOS 7 it may break lots of apps. It could just be an oversight in UIKit.

Comment: The first 'C' in "ClearColor" is capitalized? Are they changing naming convention now also??

Comment: No they didnt change the naming convention. I mentioned this to apple forum because yes many apps have UI issue after i installed io7. for example the search bas of facebook application has the native blue color not the custom color of facebook and many other apps i developed. thats why i wanted to mention this here